# Jersey Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey

У меня такая трабла - нужно написать RESTful сервис. 
В нём мне нужно работать с базой, решил для этого юзать Hibernate. 
И тут у меня встал вопрос - или я пишу сервис с помощью Jersey или с помощью Spring MVC. Потому что вместе их почти хрен соединишь, последние версии которые друг с другом работают уже староваты, и трудно подобрать это всё (пытался целый день). А соединить хотел, чтобы писать сервис с легкостью как с Jersey и ещё использовать IOC Спринга. Хотел бы у вас узнать, как лучше, взять Jersey и отказаться от Иока, или выбрать Спринг, но чуту более неудобно писать сервисы. 
Возможно я где-то ошибся в рассуждениях, опытка пока не так много.
Спасибо.

Comment: Можно одновременно использовать Spring IOC и Jersey

Comment: Jersey вполне нормально интегрируется со спрингом.